# WPF Image Color Tint

Tags: wpf, image, colors

I am loading several images in WPF and from what I have read, it keeps them all in memory.

I was wondering why it is that when I display my image, that there is a red/purple tint?

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

I set up an `Image` class using the Designer, then I set the `Image.Source` to my `ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFromString("MyFilepath.png")`

I also set

```
Image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill (if that helps)
```

It seems that some images have a reddish discoloration to them. I cannot figure out why...?

**EDIT**:

I tried to post images, but stackoverflow's convenient spam prevention said I could not post them because I just joined...

Comment: You could post the images to an image hosting service and then link to them.

Comment: Have you checked that the red/purple tint you're seeing is *real* and not just an illusion? You could use some type of color grabber (eyedropper) tool and check the image in real time against a comparison sample, or you could do a screenshot of your application running and open it up in good old Ms Paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that after I changed the images from .png to .jpg, the discoloration was no longer an issue. I am wondering what might have caused this?

I do not think it was the alpha transparency of the .png's, but rather the ImageSourceConverter itself...?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there's a translucent overlay in your XAML causing the discoloration? It could also be an encoding issue... Can you post a sample of your code?

Also, although you can't embed images directly in your post because of your newness, you could upload the image to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com), for example, and post a *link* to that image.

Answer (score 0):

This was most likely caused by dithering effect.  It should go away after you set the following property on your Image element to true:

```
SnapsToDevicePixels = "True"
```